# response error REST API CI3 not display in Client

Tags: php, rest, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I'm having a problem getting errors from the Rest API I created with codeigniter 3, or rather using the library from "https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver".

This problem occurs when I POST data to server via API.
When I try to post the same data as the data in the database. it will issue an error message data already exists. with status 409.

but I didn't get the error in the client application that I made. only displays "Null"

```
https://localhost/server/api/room

public function index_post()
{
    try {
        $input = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
        if (empty($input['noroom'])) {
            throw new Exception('Error: field not found, field must be named noroom');
            return false;
        }
        $exists = $this->Roommodel->findRoomByNoroomAndHotel($input['noroom'], $input['hotel_code'])->num_rows();
        if ($exists > 0) {
            $message = [
                'status' => 409,
                'message' => 'Data already exists',
            ];
            $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_CONFLICT);
        } else {
            $dataRoom = [
                'hotel_code'  => $input['hotel_code'],
                'noroom'      => $input['noroom'],
                'room_type'   => $input['room_type'],
                'room_area'   => $input['room_area'],
                'description' => $input['description'],
            ];
            $insert = $this->Roommodel->save($dataRoom);
            if ($insert) {
                $data = [
                    'hotel_code'  => $input['hotel_code'],
                    'noroom'      => $input['noroom'],
                    'room_type'   => $input['room_type'],
                    'room_area'   => $input['room_area'],
                    'description' => $input['description'],
                    'message'     => 'Success created data'
                ];
                $message = [
                    'status' => 200,
                    'message' => 'Success',
                    'data' => $data,
                ];
                $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_OK); 
            } else {
                $message = [
                    'status' => 400,
                    'message' => 'Bad Request'
                ];
                $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_BAD_REQUEST);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $message = [
            'status' => 500,
            'message' => $e->getMessage()
        ];
        $this->response($message, REST_Controller::HTTP_INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

below is my coding on the client side, and I try to do var_dum() the result is "Null" when there is an error.
when I tried insomia, I got the error message.

```
var $API = "";
function __construct()
{
    parent::__construct();
    $this->API = "http://localhost/server";
    $this->load->library('session');
    $this->load->library('curl');
    $this->load->helper('form');
    $this->load->helper('url');

}

public function create()
{
    if ($this->input->is_ajax_request()) {
        $data = [
            'hotel_code'  => $this->input->post('hotel_code'),
            'noroom'      => $this->input->post('noroom'),
            'room_type'   => $this->input->post('room_type'),
            'room_area'   => $this->input->post('room_area'),
            'description' => $this->input->post('description'),
        ];
        $response = json_decode($this->curl->simple_post($this->API . '/api/room', json_encode($data), array(CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE => 10)), true);
        var_dump($response); die();
        echo json_encode($response);
    }  else {
        show_404();
    }
}
```

if the post data is successful, it will send the success message. and managed to get the message.

please help me to solve this problem

Comment: Not sure if this will solve your problem but I always encounter this. This Null response usually is the result of an PHP Error in your API Server the rest is trying to call. I use POSTMAN to try to call the API and see if it will generate an error for me. you can try that and maybe there is a problem in the code you are not seeing.

Comment: no, when I call with postman, an error comes out, either an internal server error, or a bad request.
I have solved this problem by switching to guzzel